Can't get facebook user email with graph api
I face the same problem in Facebook Graph /me missing email.
As the title, I can't get my email by calling facebook graph api 'me?fields=email' now.
Pretty sure that it worked fine before.
I removed my email from my facebook profile and added it to my account again, received an email and confirmed it.
After that I called graph api '/me?fields=email', it didn't return my email, and the developer tool show a debug message "未回傳電子郵件欄位。這可能是因為電子郵件遺失、無效或未經確認。"(In English, it don't return email because the email may be missiong, invalid or not confirmed.)
This is quite weird because I have a confirmed email in my profile, how can I deal with it?
